# Bug in display 'Windows 7 Task manager'

Tags: windows-7, display, task-manager

I've installed Windows 7 on my computer. When I run the 'Windows Task manager', Menus and Tab Pages are not seen. Please help to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you see are graphs, try double clicking on one.

If you don't, but you are using third party desktop/themeing tools, try disabling them and see if that helps.